# Packer unable to communicate with AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I am just playing with packer and I created a simple template like so:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
    "aws_secret_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_KEY`}}"
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "vpc_id": "MY_DEFAULT_VPC_ID",
      "subnet_id": "MY_PUBLIC_SUBNET_ID",
      "source_ami": "ami-a025aeb6",
      "instance_type": "t2.micro",
      "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
      "ami_name": "packer-example {{timestamp | clean_resource_name}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run `packer build initial_ami.json` I get the following error.

```
amazon-ebs: output will be in this color.

==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating any provided VPC information
==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating AMI Name: packer-example 1628354042
    amazon-ebs: Found Image ID: ami-a025aeb6
==> amazon-ebs: Creating temporary keypair: packer_***********
==> amazon-ebs: Creating temporary security group for this instance: packer_****
==> amazon-ebs: Authorizing access to port 22 from [0.0.0.0/0] in the temporary security groups...
==> amazon-ebs: Launching a source AWS instance...
==> amazon-ebs: Adding tags to source instance
    amazon-ebs: Adding tag: "Name": "Packer Builder"
    amazon-ebs: Instance ID: i-******
==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for instance (i-*****) to become ready...
==> amazon-ebs: Using SSH communicator to connect: 172.**.*.**
==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH.
==> amazon-ebs: Terminating the source AWS instance...
==> amazon-ebs: Cleaning up any extra volumes...
==> amazon-ebs: No volumes to clean up, skipping
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary security group...
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary keypair...
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored after 6 minutes 51 seconds: Timeout waiting for SSH.

==> Wait completed after 6 minutes 51 seconds

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH.

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

So everything is fine until it tries to connect on the `ssh` port of the instance. It seems to be using `172....` IP so I don't think it will connect to the instance. My questions are:

1. Is this issue caused by the fact that packer is creating an instance without public IP?
2. If so, then how do I force packer to create an instance with a public IP and then use that public IP to connect to the ssh service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you not use public IP while building Packer image rather set the `ssh_interface` to `private_ip` so it can be connected from the vpc itself if you are using it as part of your ci/cd process or else you would be charge a hell lot of data transfer cost if you build them more frequently

Comment: In that case I would have to run `packer build` from an instance within the same subnet no?

Comment: It depends on your routing table how you have configured them, We prefer to run everything from our private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, all we need to do is set:

`"associate_public_ip_address": true` in the builder section of the template file.